# how do you append list of lists without using append in scheme?

Tags: scheme

Say you want append these list of lists and output a single list that contains all the numbers

```
(append-lists (list (list 1 2) 
                    (list 4 5) 
                    (list 10 19))) =>    (list 1 2 4 5 10 19)
```

If using trivial append, i can do this,

```
((define (append-lists llon)
     (cond
        [(empty? llon) empty]
        [(cons? llon)  (cons (first llon)
                       (append-lists (rest llon)))]))
```

But how to get the same output without using append just by recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of *flattening*. Some Scheme implementation feature a build-in `flatten` procedure; if not, a general flattening algorithm is :

```
(define (flatten sxp)
  (let loop ((sxp sxp) (res '()))
    (cond
      ((null? sxp) res)
      ((pair? sxp) (loop (car sxp) (loop (cdr sxp) res)))
      (else        (cons sxp res)))))
```

Testing:

```
> (flatten (list (list 1 2) (list 4 5) (list 10 19)))
'(1 2 4 5 10 19)
> (flatten (list (list 1 2) 'a (list 4 5) 'b (list 10 19)))
'(1 2 a 4 5 b 10 19)
```

Comment: @usepla thanks. i don't really follow the let loop part. can you do a simplified version?

Comment: @pnixsweet You need to get familiar with *named let*s. Have a look at [this](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/dorai/t-y-scheme/t-y-scheme-Z-H-8.html#node_sec_6.2) for example.